# Can we rename this community to Antelope?

Tags: discussion

Can we rename this community to Antelope?  EOS.IO is no longer maintained by B1. "The Coalition" is maintaining Antelope now. https://github.com/AntelopeIO/leap/

Comment: Is there a way to maintain backwards compatibility to all the literature out there that references questions? I.e. can the new name forward to the previous name's question.

Comment: Renaming makes sense. It'll help from an SEO perspective since users will be searching for answers with the term "Antelope" and the EOSIO codebase has been archived (https://github.com/eosio/eos) with no future maintenance.

Comment: I support renaming.

Comment: YES. Let's do this. I Support the renaming @StackExchange

Answer (score 7):

Long story short:

Yes, it's possible, and there are examples of other Stack Exchange sites that have been renamed.

The whole process and the requirements are not entirely clear, and I assume the first step is to get in contact with the Stack Exchange staff.

Previous examples show that it can take quite some time until the renaming happened.